# generating so files for ICU on AIX 7.1

Tags: c++, c, aix, icu

I am trying to compile ICU 49.1.2 on AIX 7.1 with vaC++ 11.1.

By default ICU make files are configured to generate .a files instead of .so files.

There is an option to change the type of shared library extension inside `/source/config/mh-aix-va` file.

SO = a -> this can be changed to so to generate so files.

But when I change it to so, I get error as below. Any idea what else has to be done to generate .so files?

```
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/cmbabu/xml/icu/source/common'
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/export/home/cmbabu/xml/icu/source/common'
gmake[1]: * No rule to make target `../lib/libicuuc.so', needed by `all-local'.  Stop.
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/cmbabu/xml/icu/source/common'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the error and successfully generate so files, I did lot of trial and errors and finally came up with a solution to as described below.

I had to modify few existing rules and add few more rules in config/mh-aix-va file.

Changes are...

line# 17 and 18: uncomment line #18

```
# If you readd this line, you must change the SO value
LDFLAGS += -brtl
```

line # 80 and 81: change the line # 81

```
# without the -brtl option, the library names use .a. AIX is funny that way.
SO= so
```

line # 92 to 99: 
comment all these lines

```
#%.a : %.so
#   ln -f $< $(SHARED_OBJECT_NO_VERSION) 
#   $(AIX_PREDELETE) $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(SHARED_OBJECT_NO_VERSION)
#   rm -f $(SHARED_OBJECT_NO_VERSION)
#$(LIBDIR)/%.a : %.so
#   ln -f $< $(SHARED_OBJECT_NO_VERSION) 
#   $(AIX_PREDELETE) $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(SHARED_OBJECT_NO_VERSION)
#   rm -f $(SHARED_OBJECT_NO_VERSION)
```

Add below lines at line # 100:

```
$(LIBDIR)/%.so : %.so
    ln -f $< $@
$(LIBDIR)/%$(SO_TARGET_VERSION).so : %.so
    ln -s $< $@
$(LIBDIR)/%$(SO_TARGET_VERSION_MAJOR).so : %.so
    ln -s $< $@
```

Answer (score 0):

AIX by default (unless you link with `-brtl`) expects shared libraries to have the suffix `.a`.  So you should not be changing `SO=a` to `SO=so` unless you also uncomment the `-brtl` flag in the makefile.

This is alluded to by the comment in the makefile:

> without the -brtl option, the library names use .a. AIX is funny that way.

Comment: I knew about it and already have un-commented. But I get the same error